# Efficient approach to get two-dimensional datau using

Tags: sql, postgresql

For the sake of example, let's say I have the following models:

- teams
- each team has an arbitrary amount of fans

In SQL, this means you end up with the following tables:

- team: identifier, name
- fan: identifier, name
- team_fan: team_identifier, fan_identifier

I am looking for an approach to retrieve:

- all teams, and
- for each team, the first 5 fans of which his/her name starts with an 'A'.

What is an efficient approach to do this?

1. In my current naive approach, I do `<# teams> + 1` queries, which is troublesome:

   - First: `SELECT * FROM team`
   - Then, for each team with identifier `X`:

     ```
     SELECT * 
     FROM fan 
       INNER JOIN team_fan 
         ON fan.identifier = team_fan.fan_identifier AND team_fan.team_identifier = X 
     WHERE fan.name LIKE 'A%' 
     ORDER BY fan.name LIMIT 5
     ```
2. There should be a better way to do this.

I could first retrieve all teams, as I do now, and then do something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fan 
WHERE fan.name LIKE 'A%' 
AND fan.identifier IN (
    SELECT fan_identifier 
    FROM team_fan 
    WHERE team_identifier IN (<all team identifiers from first query>)) 
ORDER BY fan.name
```

However, this approach ignores the requirement that I need the first 5 fans for each team with his/her name starting with an 'A'. Just adding `LIMIT 5` to the query above is not correct.

Also, with this approach, if I have a large amount of teams, I am sending the corresponding team identifiers back to the database in the second query (for the `IN (<all team identifiers from first query>)`), which might kill performance?

I am developing against PostgreSQL, Java, Spring and plain JDBC.

Comment: What if there are less than five fans whose names start with A for some teams? You don't want any first five fans in alphabetical order?

Comment: Mick: No, I want the first first 5 fans of which his/her name starts with an `A` for each team. If there are no such 5 fans for a team, then this list of fans is smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a three table join

```
SELECT team.*, fan.*
FROM team 
JOIN team_fan
  ON team.team_identifier = team_fan.team_identifier
JOIN fan
  ON fan.fan_identifier = team_fan.fan_identifier
```

Now to filter you need to do this.

```
with cte as (
    SELECT team.*, fan.*, 
           row_number() over (partition by team.team_identifier 
                              order by fan.name) as rn
    FROM team 
    JOIN team_fan
      ON team.team_identifier = team_fan.team_identifier
    JOIN fan
      ON fan.fan_identifier = team_fan.fan_identifier
    WHERE fan.name LIKE 'A%' 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte 
WHERE rn <= 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your query example. Here you are fetching `team.*` and `fan.*` in the same query. This means that, in this example, all properties of each team will be present 5 times. Isn't it better to fetch all teams first (simply `SELECT * FROM team`), and then all fans for these teams separately as you did in your query? What is the 'common sense' here? I have difficulties to assess this.

Comment: You can change to `SELECT team.id, fan.*` to reduce the data and have `SELECT team.*` in a different query. But I wouldnt worry to much about it.  You can test both query using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and see how much time take postgres execute each one. I bet the difference is minimal. And probably will take more time merge the data on the UI.

Comment: OK, interesting. I will compare with `explain analyze`. (I wish I could accept your answer, but I don't have enough reputation points so far.)

Comment: I would say that this is the most efficient way to get the data -- single query (only one roundtrip between your app and the db) and using an analytic windowing function (db does the least amount of work per query). The fact that the team information is repeated five times will likely have a marginal effect on performance. In general, you want to minimize the number of queries you run against the DB, because each query execution comes with overhead.

Comment: You can accept the answer (green tick), You can upvote soon enough *(I belive is 10 rep)*. I upvote your question to help you get there.

Comment: If I want to have these fans ordered by their name, is it correct that I have to add `ORDER BY fan.name` in the OUTER query, not the INNER query? I understand the need to order in the window function (to calculate the relevant row number), but I also want the 5 selected fans ordered.

Comment: No need. The `row_number()` already order those by name. So `rn = 1` is the first name

Comment: That's right. So I should add `ORDER BY rn` in the outer query, right?

Comment: Dont worry. For a first question was very good, actually looks like a veteran asker.

Comment: Actually you probably want `ORDER BY team.id, rn` But again depend on what you need.

Comment: I am a veteran, but new to SO :).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, RDBMSes have their own hacks around standard SQL that allows you to have a number in a count over some condition of grouping/ordering.

Postgres is no exception, it got [ROW_NUMBER()](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/) function.

What you need is to partition your row numbers properly, order them by alphabet and restrict the query to row numbers < 6.

Comment: OK, window functions, I get that. This should be done when fetching the fans for the teams returned by the first query? This means that I am sending back all team identifiers. Doesn't that kill performance?

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` and window functions in general are specified in the SQL standard, it is not a "hack around standard SQL".

Comment: @KatrineYelen I was talking about getting all in one query, not like in first case. Then, I won't use the word 'kill' - rater 'impact'. Or not. Depends on how exactly you'd implement it. Try different ones, EXPLAIN them, measure performance, make your choice.

Comment: If you do such logic in one query, aren't we repeating the team information (such as the name) 5 times?

Comment: Yes we are - so what? That's the way relational table databases work. Fetching the whole row is cheap, don't worry about that - locating it is expensive. And then it's up to you how to present it to the end user, what to cut, what to leave.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ok, ok, I may have been too ironic in there